# An isolated point in the spectrum must be a point in the approximate point spectrum??

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Is the following claim and proof correct?? I can't seem to find an error.

> Let $X$ be a complex Banach space, and $A\in \mathcal{B}(X)$ a bounded operator. Then, if $\lambda\in \sigma(A)$ is *isolated* in the spectrum, $\lambda \in \sigma_{ap}(A)$.

*Attempted proof.* Since $\lambda$ is isolated in $\sigma(A)$, there exists $r>0$ such that function $z\mapsto A_z:=(A-z)^{-1}$ is *holomorphic* on the punctured open disk $\Delta_r:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 0<|z-\lambda|<r\}$.

Assume $\lambda\notin \sigma_{ap}(A)$. That is $A_\lambda:=A-\lambda$ is *not* surjective but is *bounded below* (meaning injective and has closed range). That is
$$\delta_\lambda:=\inf_{\|x\|=1}\|(A-\lambda)(x)\|>0.$$
Then, for every sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \Delta_r$ converging to $\lambda$, such that $|z_n-\lambda|< \frac{\delta_\lambda}{2}$, and for every $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$,
$$0<\delta_\lambda-\frac{\delta_\lambda}{2}<\|(A-\lambda)(x)\|-|z_n-\lambda|\leq \|(A-z_n)(x)\|$$
Hence, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|(A-z_n)(x)\|>\frac{\delta_\lambda}{2}$, and so
$$\|(A-z_n)^{-1}\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|x\|}{\|(A-z_n)(x)\|}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\frac{1}{\|(A-z_n)(x)\|}=\frac{1}{\inf_{\|x\|=1} \|(A-z_n)(x)\|}<\frac{2}{\delta_\lambda}$$

As a result, $(A-z_n)^{-1}$ is a Cauchy sequence, since
$$\|(A-z_n)^{-1}-(A-z_m)^{-1}\|\leq |z_n-z_m|\|(A-z_n)^{-1}\|\|(A-z_n)^{-1}\|<|z_n-z_m|\left(\frac{2}{\delta_\lambda}\right)^2.$$

Then taking limit in the identity
$$(A-z_n)(A-z_n)^{-1}=(A-z_n)^{-1}(A-z_n)=Id_X,$$
and, due to continuity, we conclude $A-\lambda$ is invertible.

Contradiction. $\square$

Comment: The conclusion holds if $\lambda$ belongs to the boundary of $\sigma(A).$ I have impression that only this property has been used in your proof.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks! Indeed the only modification needed for the boundary points is $z_n$ approaching $\lambda$ from the entire punctured disk might be forbidden. But there's no real difference.